# Laravel - whereHas with where affect other rows

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application where I want to fetch parent records based on children conditionals. Current problem is that I have Students, where they have multiple study fields and study fields belong to one faculty. Pivot table `students_study_fields` has attribute `study_status_id`.

What I need is, for example, fetch all students and their study fields which belongs to "prf" faculty AND pivot has `study_status_id = 1`.

So I write a query like this.

```
return Student::with(['studyfields' => function ($query1) use ($studyStatusId, $facultyAbbreviation) {
    $query1->whereHas('pivot', function ($query2) use ($studyStatusId, $facultyAbbreviation) {
               $query2->where('study_status_id', $studyStatusId);
    });
    $query1->whereHas('studyprogram', function ($query4) use ($facultyAbbreviation) {
               $query4->whereHas('faculty', function ($query5) use ($facultyAbbreviation) {
                   $query5->where('abbreviation', $facultyAbbreviation);
               });
    });
}])->get();
```

But this query fetch students witch `study_status_id = 2` as well because exists record where this same study field (its code) has relation with student, where `study_status_id = 1`.

So I don't want to include this studyfield if somewhere exists record with `status = 1` in pivot but only if has `status = 1` for current row

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain the queries...

```
return Student::with(['studyfields' => function ($query1) use ($studyStatusId, $facultyAbbreviation) {
    $query1->whereHas('pivot', function ($query2) use ($studyStatusId, $facultyAbbreviation) {
         $query2->where('study_status_id', $studyStatusId);
    })->whereHas('studyprogram', function ($query4) use ($facultyAbbreviation) {
         $query4->whereHas('faculty', function ($query5) use ($facultyAbbreviation) {
             $query5->where('abbreviation', $facultyAbbreviation);
         });
    });
}])->get();
```

Otherwise it will re-start the query1 so you won't get `AND` kind of query, only get the second part

*Side Note: However, I want to warn you that `whereHas` is a slow query if you have many rows as it goes through each value. I personally prefer grabbing the ids with simple `->where` queries and utilise `->whereIn` approach.*

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Can you try hard-coding the `$studyStatusId` and `$facultyAbbreviation`. Or commenting out second part `->whereHas('studyprogram'`...` Comment out to see which part is causing the problem.

Comment: If I try chain `Student::with('studyfields')->whereHas(studyfields) .... ->whereHas(studyprogram) ... ` it filter by faculty but behaviour of study_status is still the same ... I tried force study_status and faculty_abb as well

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my situation

```
$students = Student::with(['studyfields' => function ($q) use ($studyStatusId) {
            $q->whereHas('pivot')->where('study_status_id', $studyStatusId);
        }])
            ->whereHas('studyfields', function ($q) use ($facultyAbbreviation) {
                $q->whereHas('studyprogram', function ($q) use ($facultyAbbreviation) {
                    $q->where('faculty_abbreviation', $facultyAbbreviation);
                });
            })
            ->get();
        $students = $students->filter(function ($student) {
            return count($student->studyfields) > 0;
        })->values();
```

Query above fetch all students from specific faculty and if studyfields array doesn't contains specific study_status, leave empty array so later I can filter collection from empty arrays assuming that each student belongs to at least one studyfield.